# Flutter Records Automated Tests with Mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I am currently using records in a method and apparently mockito does not generate the code for it in the test case. Below is my method...

```
Future<(FileModel, Uint8List)> updateHomeImage(
      {File? image, Uint8List? bytes, Uint8List? imageBytes}) async {
    try {
      return kIsWeb
          ? await createImage(imageBytes: imageBytes, category: 'home-picture')
          : await createImage(image: image, category: 'home-picture');
    } on Exception {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

The error occurs in the test file as shown below:
Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

```
test/cases/providers/home_provider_test.mocks.dart:1541:16: Error: Type 'FileModel' not found.
  _i13.Future<(FileModel, Uint8List)> createImage({
               ^^^^^^^^^
test/cases/providers/home_provider_test.mocks.dart:1541:27: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
  _i13.Future<(FileModel, Uint8List)> createImage({
                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Edit: I have updated my question with the createImage method, please, see it below:

```
Future<(FileModel, Uint8List)> createImage({
    File? image,
    Uint8List? imageBytes,
    String? category,
  }) async {
    logger.fine('createImage called');
    var uri = Uri.parse('$filesPath/');
    FormData? formData;
    Options? options;
    Uint8List? bytes = Uint8List(0);

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        Map<String, dynamic> mapData = {
          'file': MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            imageBytes!,
            filename: 'image.png',
            contentType: MediaType.parse('image/png'),
          ),
          'category': category,
        };
        formData = FormData.fromMap(mapData);

        options = Options(
          headers: {
            ...headers,
            'File-Path': 'image.png',
          },
        );
      } else {
        String fileName = image!.path.split('/').last;
        Map<String, dynamic> mapData = {
          'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            image.path,
            filename: fileName,
            contentType: MediaType.parse('image/${image.path.split('.').last}'),
          ),
          'category': category,
        };
        formData = FormData.fromMap(mapData);

        options = Options(
          headers: {
            ...headers,
            'File-Path': image.path,
          },
        );
      }

      var response = await interceptedDio.postUri(
        uri,
        data: formData,
        options: options,
      );

      switch (imageBytes == null) {
        case true:
          return (FileModel.fromFileModelJson(response.data), bytes);
        default:
          return (FileModel.fromFileModelJson(response.data), imageBytes!);
      }
    } on DioException catch (e, s) {
      switch (e.type) {
        case DioExceptionType.cancel:
          logger.warning('request canceled');
          throw RequestCanceledException('request canceled');
        default:
          logger.shout('unhandled exception', e);
          await Sentry.captureException(e, stackTrace: s);
          throw Exception(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: what is inside `createImage`?

Comment: edit my question with the createImage